# How to fix error after creating any Android app in Eclipse?

Tags: android

I'm newbie and I installed Eclipse 12-2018, SDK tools 25.2.5, Android Support Repository:

[image: Extras]

But I can't install Android Support Library and have this error when I create any Android app. See this error:

```
[2019-01-16 21:16:10 - First] D:\EclipseWorkspace\First\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2019-01-16 21:16:10 - First] 
[2019-01-16 21:16:10 - First] D:\EclipseWorkspace\First\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2019-01-16 21:16:10 - First] 
[2019-01-16 21:16:10 - First] D:\EclipseWorkspace\First\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2019-01-16 21:16:10 - First] 
[2019-01-16 21:16:12 - First] D:\EclipseWorkspace\First\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2019-01-16 21:16:12 - First] 
[2019-01-16 21:16:12 - First] D:\EclipseWorkspace\First\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2019-01-16 21:16:12 - First] 
[2019-01-16 21:16:12 - First] D:\EclipseWorkspace\First\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2019-01-16 21:16:12 - First] 
[2019-01-16 21:16:14 - First] D:\EclipseWorkspace\First\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2019-01-16 21:16:14 - First] 
[2019-01-16 21:16:14 - First] D:\EclipseWorkspace\First\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2019-01-16 21:16:14 - First] 
[2019-01-16 21:16:14 - First] D:\EclipseWorkspace\First\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2019-01-16 21:16:14 - First]
```

I know that the same questions were discussed yet but those answers didn't help me.

Comment: Google has not supported Eclipse in years, and I am not aware of any other group that is supporting Eclipse for Android app development. Please use something that somebody supports, such as Android Studio.

Comment: I can't because I have low-power PC. It's too hard to wait when project builds in Android Studio every time and to write applications with slow PC. So, I must have money to be Android developer and I'm nothing without modern PC? I have 4 GB RAM, AMD A8 7410 2.2 GHz processor, haven't SSD, AMD Radeon A7 m440 2 Gb grafics card

Comment: "I must have money to be Android developer and I'm nothing without modern PC" -- no, but at the same time, you need to choose tools that are supported. If I were in your position, I would look into hybrid app frameworks that support building apps without Android Studio.